# Does keyboard language affect login password?

Tags: login, password, input-language

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

This OS was installed with my machine's default keyboard AZERTY: `Fr`, that's the French keyboard. But I often prefer using QWERTY: `En`, so I often set it to that. But during login, after my pc sleeps, if the keyboard is still set to `En` The QWERTY corresponding keys to type in my password fails to log me in, but if I reset it to `Fr` it's AZERTY corresponding keys logs me in.

This is actually not much of a problem to me but what I need to know is if Ubuntu 16.04 LTS verifies the password by:

a) whatever form of the entered text in the password field.

or

b) the logic of the key combinations hit.

or

c) some other means, in which case, what and how?

Thanks.

Comment: The password consists of a string of characters, so yes, which keys to press depends on the effective keyboard layout. If you are using `unity-greeter`, I think you can switch layout from the login screen, though.

Comment: As far as I understand it is the ascii characters that are checked by the login system, A is ascii 65 etc, and this is independent of the keyboard setting. But you may have to press different keys to get an A. -- There can be problems with characters, that appear only in some keyboard settings, for example characters with umlaut (for example Ä), so it is a good idea to use a password with standard ascii characters, that are available in most keyboard settings.

Comment: Right-click on the password text box, and select to view the characters, so you can see what is actually benign typed. See if the key presses correspond to what you expect.